# Find all points $ (X_{0},Y_{0}) $ in the the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all points $ (X_{0},Y_{0}) $  in the the ODE $ \ y'=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\ln(xy)} \ $ , $ y(X_{0})=Y_{0} $ has unique solution in some interval containing $ X_{0} $.

The ODE is  $ \ y'=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\ln(xy)} \ $ , $ y(X_{0})=Y_{0} $ .

or, $ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\ln(xy)} $.

This equation is not separable , I think . So I can not find analytical solution.

Now ,  $ f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\ln(xy)} $  exists when $ \ \ xy>0 \ \ $ . So solution exists in the $ 1st \ \ and \ \ 3rd $ quadrant.  **But How can I find the subintervals ? Any help is there ?**

Comment: Actually, $f(x,y)$ exists (and is regular) at points $(x,y)$ such that $xy>0$ and $xy\ne1$. This is the answer to your question.